# How to get/calculate the sum of child nodes for their parent node through jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a data in ***json format*** like this. this is hierarchical data with parent child relation.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "AccountName": "a",
      "ParentID": "",
      "OpeningDebit": 0,
      "OpeningCredit": 0
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "AccountName": "b",
      "ParentID": "1",
      "OpeningDebit": 0,
      "OpeningCredit": 0
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "AccountName": "c",
      "ParentID": "2",
      "OpeningDebit": 100,
      "OpeningCredit": 200
    },
    {
      "ID": "4",
      "AccountName": "d",
      "ParentID": "2",
      "OpeningDebit": 50,
      "OpeningCredit": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Parent child relationship maintained by `ID` and `ParentID` properties . Like the record with `ID` 2 is child record of the  record with `ID` 1.

I want to sum of `OpeningDebit` and `OpeningCredit` property of all there children node and set it to their parent node. Remember only node that `Transactional` (Mentioned in their Property `Type`), has values.

My desire result is

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "AccountName": "a",
      "ParentID": "",
      "OpeningDebit": 150,
      "OpeningCredit": 210
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "AccountName": "b",
      "ParentID": "1",
      "OpeningDebit": 150,
      "OpeningCredit": 210
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "AccountName": "c",
      "ParentID": "2",
      "OpeningDebit": 100,
      "OpeningCredit": 200
    },
    {
      "ID": "4",
      "AccountName": "d",
      "ParentID": "2",
      "OpeningDebit": 50,
      "OpeningCredit": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

I want ***javascript*** function that can sum for all my Parent Node. may be it can be achieve through recursive function because this is nth level hierarchal data , like some nodes has 3 level and some has 5 .

Comment: data came from server through API and I want it to calculate on client side code like jQuery or javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a recursive function that calculate the sum of `OpeningDebit` and `OpeningCredit`, with the base case of when the data has no children, return its own value

Below snippet could help you

```js
const { data } = {
  data: [
    {
      ID: "1",
      AccountName: "a",
      ParentID: "",
      OpeningDebit: 0,
      OpeningCredit: 0,
    },
    {
      ID: "2",
      AccountName: "b",
      ParentID: "1",
      OpeningDebit: 0,
      OpeningCredit: 0,
    },
    {
      ID: "3",
      AccountName: "c",
      ParentID: "2",
      OpeningDebit: 100,
      OpeningCredit: 200,
    },
    {
      ID: "4",
      AccountName: "d",
      ParentID: "2",
      OpeningDebit: 50,
      OpeningCredit: 10,
    },
  ],
}

const res = data.map((d) => {
  const getSum = (obj, prop) => {
    const children = data.filter(({ ParentID }) => ParentID === obj.ID)
    if (children.length === 0) return obj[prop]
    return children.reduce((acc, c) => acc + getSum(c, prop), 0)
  }

  return {
    ...d,
    OpeningDebit: getSum(d, "OpeningDebit"),
    OpeningCredit: getSum(d, "OpeningCredit"),
  }
})

console.log({ data: res })
```